# Pass the result of a helper to another helper?

Tags: express, handlebars.js

Is there a way I can invoke a helper inside a helper in handlebars? I would like to do something like this:

```
{{#each myCustomHelper}}
<li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Where the invocation of myCustomHelper returns an array of strings.

I'm trying to do this from node using express-handlebars and I do not want to pass that array of strings on each res.render.
I would like to avoid also outputting html from myCustomHelper.
Is the above possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And found the answer. At least in my case the syntax will be:

```
{{#each (myCustomHelper)}}
<li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Had to dig into this [issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/304#issuecomment-15635762) to find the correct syntax